# I am getting "no such file to load -- aws/s3" even though I have it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, amazon-s3

```
$ sudo gem install aws-s3

$ irb -rubygems
$ require 'aws/s3'

=> true
```

So I have the gem everything works.. but now I console into my application..

```
$ script/console
$ require 'aws/s3'

MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- aws/s3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/radiant-0.9.1/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/radiant-0.9.1/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/radiant-0.9.1/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/radiant-0.9.1/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from (irb):1
```

What could that be from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what your problem is, but depending on your rails version you should make sure you have the gem specified in your `Gemfile` (rails-3) or in your `environment.rb` (rails 2).

Once you fix this problem I suggest you take the time to learn more about managing gems, it's not a difficult topic and will pay dividends. I suggest looking into [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and break the habit of using `sudo` to install gems.

If you are on Rails 2 you should also consider either upgrading to rails 3 or [using bundler](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/03/using-the-new-gem-bundler-today/) (this is an old link, but I think the instructions should still work).

Comment: Yikes I'm retarded. I forgot I already had bundler installed in this rails 2.3.5 project and wasn't bundling the gem. Thanks for the tip!